# .NET MAUI Community Toolkit Popup PopupHandler is incompatible

Tags: popup, maui

I started working with .NET MAUI. I ran into a problem just by starting my development.
I want to show a popup and I'm using the Community Toolkit.

All I did is:

I created a new .NET MAUI Application Project, installed the Community Toolkit NuGet Package (of course also the .UseMauiCommunityToolkit in the start up class) and added a XAML File for the Popup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
               x:Class="TestApp.ProfilePopup">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="This is a very important message!" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</toolkit:Popup>
```

I've no partial class for this popup

I just modified the button on MainPage to display the popup:

```
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var popup = new ProfilePopup();

        this.ShowPopup(popup);

    }
```

If I run this application and click on the button to display the popup I'll get the error message:

`CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Handlers.PopupHandler found for TestApp.ProfilePopup is incompatible`

If I create the popup in C#, it works:

```
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = new Popup
        {
            Content = new VerticalStackLayout
            {
                Children =
        {
            new Label
            {
                Text = "This is a very important message!"
            }
        }
            }
        };

        this.ShowPopup(popup);

    }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Markus

Comment: I think this looks like a bug on the toolkit. Are you able to raise the issue over in the repository? https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui

Comment: Bug is in code shown in question, not in Toolkit Popup. See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I reproduced the error message.

THE CAUSE: *"I've no partial class for this popup"*.

That won't work. without that, there is no `InitializeComponent` call. The result is not a valid View.

---

To fix the problem,

First make sure you have got the toolkit registered in `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
...

builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit();
```

then you must have

file `ProfilePopup.xaml.cs` containing:

```cs
public partial class ProfilePopup : CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup
{
    public ProfilePopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

---

I generate custom views using these steps:

1. Project / Add New Item / .NET MAUI ContentView (XAML).
2. Give name "MyView". This adds TWO files to project: `MyView.xaml` and `MyView.xaml.cs`.
3. In `MyView.xaml`, add needed xmlns and change base class.
   Was:

```xml
<ContentView xmlns=...
    ...
    x:Class=...>
...
</ContentView>
```

change to:

```xml
<toolkit:Popup xmlns=
    ...
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    x:Class=...>
...
</toolkit:Popup>
```

4. In `MyView.xaml.cs`, change base class.
   Was:

```cs
public partial class ProfilePopup : ContentView
```

change to:

```cs
public partial class ProfilePopup : CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup
```

Comment: If `InitializeComponent()` gives a compile error of "undefined", make sure that the XAML `x:Class="MyProj.a.b.popup"` matches the namespace of the C# code.  One might think that InitializeComponent() should exist in class Popup, but apparently that gets created from the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I forgot to add `.UseMauiCommunityToolkit();` to `MauiProgram.cs`.

You can try this, as well:

```
var popup = new PopupPage();
await PopupExtensions.ShowPopupAsync<PopupPage>(this, popup);
```